# Function to parse string with tokens

Tags: c++, parsing

I know how to program in C# and VB but not have idea about how to use C++ and have to program a little exe to a barcode scanner that use C++ :(

In this moment I try to parse a scanned barcode that have multiple data sepparated with a "/", I find that exist a strtok function, tested it "manually" and worked ok but I not implemented yet a working function to call it correctly, what I have now:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int elemStr(char *str, char sep)
{
   int cantElem;
   unsigned ich;

   cantElem = 0;

   if (strlen(str) > 0) //at least 1 elem
      cantElem++;

   for (ich = 0; ich < strlen(str); ich++)
   {         
      if (str[ich] == sep)
         cantElem++;      
   }                
   return cantElem;
}

char* getElemStr(char *str, char sep[], int elem)
{   
    char *tempStr = NULL;
    char *tok;                   
    int currElem = 1;

    // 1st data
    strcpy( tempStr, str);
    tok = strtok( tempStr, sep);

    while( currElem != elem )
    {       
        // Get next tokens:
        tok = strtok( NULL, sep );
        currElem++;
    }

    return tok;
}


void main( void )
{
    char barcode[] = "710015733801Z/1/35";

    char sep[] = "/";
    char sep1 = sep[0];

    char barcd[20];
    char piezaChar[4];
    int pieza;
    char mtsChar[4];

    int cantElem;

    cantElem = elemStr(barcode, sep1 );

    if (cantElem >= 1)
    {
        strcpy(barcd, getElemStr(barcode,sep,1) ); //pasa a str resultado;
        printf("Cod: %s\n", barcd ); //STACK OVERFLOW HERE!
    }
 }
```

if I use strtok witout a function "getElemStr" it work ok but I try to use it on other places too.

Can I use strtok like this? You have a working example? 
pd: I not have idea about pointers (sorry), good doc to learn about that?

Comment: Just FYI, this is not really "idiomatic C++", but more like C code compiled with a C++ compiler. If you want to use "real C++" for this, read up on `stringstream`, it will make this a lot easier.

Comment: thanks, I see a <strstrea.h> that I can include... I will see if I can do a working "function" with this

Comment: The header for `stringstream` is `<sstream>`

Comment: I just noticed the title of this question before it was changed.  Are you really using Visual C++ 1.52?  Because if that's the case, then I think you will have serious problems implementing mine or even badgerr's solution.  Please get a modern compiler, such as [Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/), it's free.

Comment: If you need a modern C++ DOS compiler, try [Digital Mars](http://www.digitalmars.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a C++ solution that doesn't use boost.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string barcode = "710015733801Z/1/35";

    std::stringstream ss(barcode);
    std::string elem;

    while(std::getline(ss, elem, '/'))
    {
        //do something else meaningful with elem
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
710015733801Z
1
35
```

Comment: I see that I have string.h, sstream.h and iostream.h, I will see if I can adapt this example to this compiler.

Comment: thanks, I see that this scanner doesn't support using those libraries,   has rubenvb says on my question comment, it's like that it uses C and use the C++ compiler
Seems that it only accepts a subset of libraries, I will have to use strtok witout a method :( thanks for the example and the help, I think that if this scanner worked with vc++ this example can be the better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since you specifically asked about C++, I'm going to ignore your very c-style code and show you how to do this in C++:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string barcode = "710015733801Z/1/35";

    std::string sep = "/";
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    boost::split(v, barcode, boost::is_any_of(sep));

    for(size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << v[i] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: you can equally (or better still, less dependencies) use a `stringstream` and `getline` where you specify a seperator.

Comment: @rubenvb: That will work of course, but I don't really consider that better.  In my opinion, everybody learning C++ should be advised to install boost immediately, and consider it part of their standard library.  Once that is done, the boost solution is much simpler and clearer than the stringstream solution.

Comment: @Benjamin I must disagree with your point. You make it sound like Boost is the be-all and end-all of C++ programming. It's not.

Comment: @badgerr:  Which point?  Because I didn't say that "Boost is the be-all and end-all of C++ programming"

Comment: @Benjamin Sorry, didn't mean to put words in your mouth. That's just the impression I got from your suggestion for learners to immediately install boost and consider it part of their standard library.

Comment: c++ 1.52 is too old, I need to compile with this compiler (DOS EXE for Scanner that only compiles with this compiler) .. it uses "#include <xxxxxx.h>" and doesn't have "::", etc..., because this I need some C or C++ library/methods that are compatible with this C++ compiler and allows me to create methods that are compatible and works on that scanner.

Comment: thanks for the example, appears that my scanner (symbol pdt series 3000) only accepts a subset of classes and use the c++ compiler but only some c libraries are accepted.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` destroys your original string. So i don't think it can be used with a char* that points to a static string. Static strings get copied to a read only portion of the executable.

Comment: thanks.
Exists a solution that not use strtok that I can use?